# R DataFrame: conditional transformation for linked data

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe of nodes. The dataframe can be created with this,

```
t1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1) #type 1
t2 <- c(1,0,1,0,1) #type 1

t3 <- c(1,1,0,0,1) #type 2
t4 <- c(1,1,0,0,1) #type 2

t5 <- c(1,0,1,0,1) #type 1
t6 <- c(1,0,1,0,1)


df <- data.frame(rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5))
names(df) <- c('n1','n2','n3','n4','n5')
df
```

The dataframe looks like this,

```
   n1 n2 n3 n4 n5
t1  1  0  1  0  1
t2  1  0  1  0  1
t3  1  1  0  0  1
t4  1  1  0  0  1
t5  1  0  1  0  1
```

I want to achieve a transformed dataframe that is similar to an adjacency metrics. The first row can be transformed like this,

```
n1 n3 1 # Means, 1 link from n1 to n3
n3 n5 1 # Means, 1 link from n3 to n5
```

Another example, the fourth row would be transformed like this,

```
n1 n2 1
n2 n5 1
```

Now my question is, can I achieve this using any built-in R function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from `tidyverse`. `df2` is the final output.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Process the data
df2 <- df %>%
  rownames_to_column("ID") %>%
  gather(From, Occur, -ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, From) %>%
  filter(Occur != 0) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(To = lead(From)) %>%
  drop_na(To) %>%
  select(ID, From, To, Occur)

# View the result. df2 holds the transformed data
df2
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
      ID  From    To Occur
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1    t1    n1    n3     1
 2    t1    n3    n5     1
 3    t2    n1    n3     1
 4    t2    n3    n5     1
 5    t3    n1    n2     1
 6    t3    n2    n5     1
 7    t4    n1    n2     1
 8    t4    n2    n5     1
 9    t5    n1    n3     1
10    t5    n3    n5     1
```